# How to use dynamically generated filenames in \IfFileExists?

Tags: macros, conditionals, loops, external-files

I have a file `0012` in the directory of the following `tex` file. I want to check the existence or non-existence of files inside the `\forloop` from 11 to 13.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{numprint}
\newcounter{ct} 
\newcommand{\fileno}{\npfourdigitnosep\nplpadding{4}\numprint{\arabic{ct}}}
\usepackage{forloop}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
    \forloop{ct}{11}{\value{ct} < 14} { 
        % \IfFileExists{0012} {
        \IfFileExists{\fileno} {
           fileno: "\fileno{}" exists! \\
        } {       
           fileno: "\fileno{}" doesn't exist! \\
        }
    }    
\end{document}
```

I get this compile error:

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 15.
<inserted text>
                \fi
```

I have no compiler error if I switch to

```
\IfFileExists{0012}
```

which produces this output:

```
ﬁleno: ”0011” exists!
ﬁleno: ”0012” exists!
ﬁleno: ”0013” exists!
```

**How can I check the existence of files with my `\fileno` macro?**

I want this output:

```
ﬁleno: ”0011” doesn't exist!
ﬁleno: ”0012” exists!
ﬁleno: ”0013” doesn't exist!
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `\IfFileExists` expects something that expands to a string of characters, the file name. However the macros in `numprint` can't safely expand to just strings because they do assignments and so on. You could do the settings (I suppose they are settings) `\npfourdigitnosep\nplpadding{4}` *outside* of `\IfFileExists`, but then `\numprint` itself isn't expandable, so you'd have to figure out a way to store the printed number and *only then* pass it to `\IfFileExists`. Too much work :-)

With `xparse` and a few `expl3` funcions you can make `\fileno` safely expandable `:D`

I made the `\fileno` macro take an optional argument, then a mandatory argument. The optional argument is the width of the number to print. If no optional argument is given, the default is 4. The mandatory argument is the actual number to be printed.

I took the liberty to create a `\forloop` macro with `expl3` as well. You can use the one from the `forloop` package here, it wasn't causing the problem. The new `\forloop` macro has the syntax: `\forloop{<first>}[<step>]{<last>}{<code>}`, where `<first>` and `<last>` are the beginning and end of the loop, `<step>` is the increment (the default is 1), and the `<code>` is arbitrary TeX code to be executed at each iteration of the loop. Inside the `<code>` the current value of the loop counter is available as `#1`.

Creating two sample files `0011` and `0013` the output is:

> [image]

Code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \fileno { O{4} m }
  { \exp_args:Nf \kopi_leading_zeros:nn { \int_eval:n {#2} } {#1} }
\cs_new:Npn \kopi_leading_zeros:nn #1 #2
  { \prg_replicate:nn { #2 - \str_count:n {#1} } { 0 } \int_eval:n {#1} }
\NewDocumentCommand \forloop { m O{1} m m }
  { \int_step_inline:nnnn {#1} {#2} {#3} {#4} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Dummy files
\begin{filecontents}{0011}
blub
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{0013}
zzzz
\end{filecontents}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\forloop{11}{13}{%
  \IfFileExists {\fileno{#1}} {%
    fileno: ``\fileno{#1}'' exists! \\
  } {%
    fileno: ``\fileno{#1}'' doesn't exist! \\
  }%
}
\end{document}
```