# Is there a command, macro or tool that can get the string result (as in other languages) of any macro in an easy to use way?

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion, strings

I don't want to go down into the depths of expandable and not expandable. I doubt that I will be able to understand my self-developed designs a few weeks later. Therefore I am looking for a universal and easy to use solution.

Is there anything like that?

I think somewhere in the depths of TeX there must be a point where every macro, as far as it creates strings, must have a knowledge of those strings - finally, letters will be typeset!

The question is, how can you hook up to this point?

Comment: You cannot (terms and conditions may apply). I suppose this is related to your other question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/507959), right? In TeX a control sequence (`\<something>`) is either a macro, which can expand, or a primitive, which may or may not expand. If it is "expandable" it means it can appear in an expansion-only context, like when TeX is looking for a file name. If it can't expand, it is sent to a deeper level in TeX, outside of your control. So no, even if some macro (like `\numprint`) generates a string, if it isn't expandable you can't simply take control over it.

Comment: Terms and conditions: In LuaTeX you have `\immediateassignment` and `\immediateassigned` (see section 2.8.8 of the LuaTeX manual), which make some unexpandable operations (namely assignments) expandable,. so you could perhaps use that to circumvent TeX's expansion mechanism. Of course that applies to LuaTeX only, and even the manual says "But this kind of expansion it still doesn’t expand some primitive operations", so there might be some things you won't be able to do.

Comment: As @PhelypeOleinik says, for a non-expandable macro, there is no point at which _the whole result_ is one 'string'. You get instructions to work something out, and that results in one or more chars to typeset, then you get more instructions, _etc._ One can write non-expandable code to _store_ the result in a known place, but that depends on the code being written that way.

Comment: tex does not have a string type so basically the answer to your question is "no" or to put it another way any answer must ignore your request not to discuss expansion.

Comment: @David Carlisle tag `strings`? packages: `stringstrings`, `xstring`, `coolstr`, `stringenc`? I want exactly one general solution for all cases that can be based internally on expansion or not.

Comment: None of those packages deal with strings as understood in other programming languages that have a string type.  There is no general solution as most macros do not expand to a sequence of character tokens (the nearest thing TeX has to a string)

Comment: @CarpeDiemKopi Section 1.1 *Description* of `xstring`: "This extension provides macros and tests operating on ”strings of tokens”, as other programmation languages have." Section 1.2 *Motivation*: "[...] I have never really found tools in LaTeX suiting my needs for strings". Never forget that before everything else TeX is just a program to put text on paper, so it doesn't need to get into the depths of data types and provide "strings". It just needs characters to be put on paper. Of course some people (me included) have nothing better to do and provide interfaces to try to emulate that :-)

Comment: consider a macro defined like `\def\zz{café}` what string do you want out of it? In the default OT1 encoding this expands to `caf\unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \let \unhbox \voidb@x \setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {e
\global \mathchardef \accent@spacefactor \spacefactor }\accent 19 e\egroup \spacefactor \accent@spacefactor`  In the T1 encoding it expands to `caf�` (bad UTF-8 as it uses T1 which is sometimes but not always like ISO-88591 encoding, but is never UTF), and on lualatex it expands to `café`  and that is a _really simple_ example, most macros have more complicated constructs than an e acute.

Comment: @Pelype Oleinik I've come up with a brute force method: I compile with 2 runs and write out in the first one only the relevant strings with "|" separated.  I extract the strings with go (much faster than JavaScript, easier than C/C++/C#) from the pdf into another file and use this one for the second pass. I will compare the runtimes with your solution to my other question.

Comment: @David Carlisle That's a very good example, but it falls under the restriction I made: `as far as it creates strings`.

Comment: @CarpeDiemKopi yes but there is no way in advance of knowing which macros "make strings" especially in the absence of a definition of "string"

Comment: @David Carlisle With my brute force method of writing the "strings" in a first pass to pdf I get `café` for your example (`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`). In my solution, the user decides what's a "string".

Comment: @CarpeDiemKopi all of those get something that _looks like café_ in the generated PDF that is rather the point. TeX never constructs anything remotely like a string, it just, after executing more or less arbitrary assignments happens to have put those letters visually close to each other, so the heuristics in your pdf reader (and your eyes) treat it as a single string when extracting text from the pdf., but to tex it looks more like a program than a string: `print c; check for c-a kerns; print a; check for a-f kerns; print f; construct acute accent over e; print constructed letter.`

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments, TeX doesn't know about strings but only about expandable and executable macros and primitives. When TeX processes its input it starts expanding tokens as far as necessary to find an unexpandable command with its parameters or output characters. It then starts executing those if they are commands, or adds them to the built page if they are characters.

It's still not exactly clear what kind of result you are looking for or what you want to do with it. But from your comments above it seems you are just looking for a fully expanded version of some token list, i.e. a series of tokens which only produces printable characters without any unexpandable commands in between. If that's the case, you can use `\edef\mystring{<tokens>}` to fully expand the token list `<tokens>` and store the resulting "string" in the macro `\mystring`:

```
\def\a{a}
\def\b{\a b}
\def\c{\b-\b-\b c}

\edef\mystring{\c}
\show\mystring
```

will print

```
> \mystring=macro:
->ab-ab-abc.
```

on the terminal. Depending on what you want to do with that result, you'd have to use further expansion methods to "unpack" the macro.